# How to query CloudKit by lastModifiedUserRecordID?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

Based on Apple documentation, lastModifiedUserRecordID, is a system field that's auto generated on iCloud.

I want to fetch records from the public iCloud database that where last modified by me.

I set "modifiedBy" as Queryable on the CloudKit Dashboard and added this predicate:

```
let userId = CKRecord.Reference(recordID: userCKRecordID, action: .none)
lastModifiedPred = NSPredicate(format: "lastModifiedUserRecordID = %@", userId)
```

And it returns no results. If I remove this predicate, it returns 1 result and I can see in the dashboard that the last modified by record id (recordName) matches with the user recordName I'm sending it.

Oddly enough, using "creatorUserRecordID" and passing the same value as above does return proper results but I need lastModifiedBy.

EDIT: Per the suggestions I tried to use the actual userCKRecord.recordName as a string and sending this predicate to CloudKit.

```
lastModifiedPred = NSPredicate(format: "lastModifiedUserRecordID = %@", userCKRecord.recordName)
```

and received this error:

> "Field \'___modifiedBy\' has a value type of REFERENCE and cannot be
>   queried using filter value type STRING"

As I mentioned above, I can query creatorUserRecordID just fine using the original predicate at the top (using CKRecord.ID), but it just doesn't work for lastModifiedUserRecordID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to fetch records that were last modified by you, you have to get first your `UserRecordID`. This is done by calling

```
fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: { (myUserRecordID, error) in
… // see below
}
```

see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1399191-fetchuserrecordid).  This way, you get your user `myUserRecordID`.
With this, you can setup your query predicate:

```
let lastModifiedPred = NSPredicate(format: "lastModifiedUserRecordID = %@", myUserRecordID)
```

and execute your query.

Comment: This worked. I swear I tried this and got an error that I needed a REFERENCE type (rather than giving it a CKRecord.ID, as you are doing now) which led me down the path in my op, but I just re-tried this and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `NSPredicate` to compare a string literal. Where userId is not a string literal. Use this.

```
lastModifiedPred = NSPredicate(format: "lastModifiedUserRecordID = %d", INT-VALUE-OF-userId)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, the userId value is similar to a GUID so can't be converted to an Int.

Answer (score 0):

Based on apple documentation on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/id

**CKRecord.ID ->  class ID : NSObject**

> A record ID object consists of a name string and a zone ID. The name
>   string is an ASCII string not exceeding 255 characters in length.

comparing an object and string won't give you the result, try to cast the CKRecord.ID as String maybe help

Comment: I decided to try this and received this error: "Field \'___modifiedBy\' has a value type of REFERENCE and cannot be queried using filter value type STRING"